# FirebaseRecyclerOptions setQuery clarification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

[image]

I was trying to fetch the details "Enquires" node (as shown in figure) to another activity using recycler view. I initially thought I need to give message keys (like MYjgqE-tUzu-RabI2Us and MYjhuBob1C41bT2_zkI) as child in setQuery path, but
when I wrote code with out that keys like this
`FirebaseRecyclerOptions<EnquiryModelClass> options =new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<EnquiryModelClass>().setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Enquires"),EnquiryModelClass.class) .build();`I was able to fech the data and correctly displayed in the activity. I am just curious to know why message keys are not required.?? In some childEvent listeners also I noticed that people didnt give userIds (child) in the path, why that is so??

Comment: I also thought of this..but didnt know..hope somebody will answer